# How to use maven GAE archetype with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, maven, maven-archetype

Im using the maven GAE skeleton archetype.
I've created the project and used mvn eclipse:eclipse so that I could import it as an Eclipse project.

When I make the import, it imports three projects:

- MyApp
- MyApp-war
- MyApp-ear

Do I have to import the three projects or just the first one?

What I really need is to know how to organize my project structure and directories. Can I put everything into the main project?

I will be using Spring MVC, where should I put the controllers and the .JSPs?

What is the purpose of the ear and war projects? I followed the tutorials and I setup the project, but I don't know exactly how to use it.
I'm new to this technologies, so I'm sorry if its a stupid question.

Thanks in advance!